# Ayuda en laravel 5 y ajax. Obtener un valor de la base de datos

Tags: jquery, ajax, laravel, laravel-5

Quiero que en mi vista, al momento de seleccionar algo en mi dropdown, se ejecute un método que tengo en mi controlador, éste realiza otra función(query) en mi modelo, la cual saca un dato(int) de una tabla.
Me ocurre un error al debuggear con chrome, les dejo el link de la foto 
Estoy usando ajax, en el que no soy muy experto por si es que me pueden echar una mano o decirme que estoy haciendo mal.
Otro dato mi dropdown esta dentro de un formulario, por lo que he visto algunos ejemplos con formulario con Post lo cual no me sirve, ya que lo que quiero hacer es por client-side. Ya que un usuario estará haciendo eso.

[image: Función del modelo]

[image: Controlador y su función]

Script

```
   $("#sociedad").change(function(){

      $.get("imp/"+event.target.value+"",function(response, sociedad){
          console.log(response);
      });
 });
```

Rutas

```
Route::resource('venta','VentasController'); 
Route::get('imp/{id}',  'VentasController@getIva');
```

Vista y formulario

```
<div class="form-group">                                
{!!Form::select('msocod_id',['' => '- Seleccione una sociedad -'] +$soci,null, ['class' => 'form-control','id'=>'sociedad', 'name'=>'sociedad'])!!} 
</div>
```

Form

```
@extends('layouts.principal')
@section('content')

@include('alerts.request')
{!!Form::open(['route'=>'venta.store','method'=>'POST'])!!} 

@include('venta.forms.venta')

{!!Form::close()!!}
@section('script')
{!!Html::script('js/script.js')!!}
@stop
@stop
```

Comment: Aqui les dejo la foto del error: http://fotos.subefotos.com/31b0b8449347ef7288bf797f733871b4o.png

Comment: Qué pasa si intentas `$.get("/imp/"+event.target.value....` (agregar un / al comienzo de la url).

Comment: Hola Shaz, me sale esto: Object {}. Creo que no esta enviando nada al parecer. pero ya no me sale el error.
Ahora no entiendo por qué no rescata algún dato.

Comment: Me puedes echar una mano Shaz?

Comment: Se supone según el método getIva que le estás pasando un valor `msocod_id`, pero no veo por ningún lado que lo estés pasando en el `get`

Comment: Te refieres al $.get del script? Si es así, como podría hacerlo? Ya que soy mas o menos novato en ajax

Comment: Listo, ya lo pasé  funciona...ahora la otra duda que tengo es como rescato el valor int de esa columna? o sea lo que estoy rescatando ahora es: [{"mimpts":"19"}] y lo que necesito seria solo el 19 que es un int. Si me puedes ayudar Shaz.

Comment: Eso no es más que un array json, solo necesitas acceder la clave mimpts y listo.

Comment: Gracias Shaz, puede acceder a la clave, ahora si problema resuleto 100%

Answer (score 2, accepted):

La ruta que está usando la función get de jQuery es relativa, lo cual resulta en una ruta incorrecta (404), hay que agregar entonces un `/` al comienzo de la misma para hacer un referenciamiento absoluto, partiendo desde la raíz del dominio actual:

```
  $.get("/imp/"+event.target.value, function(response, sociedad) {
      console.log(response);
  });
```

Comment: Muchas gracias, ya solucioné ese problema.

Comment: Si la respuesta te sirvió, puedes marcarla como aceptada.